# I want to extract login details from a csv file in my php. My code only accepts the last values in the csv file

Tags: php, arrays, loops, csv, authentication

I want to extract login details from a csv file in my php. My code only accepts the last values in the csv file.
This is my code.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $username= $_POST['name'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        $file_handle = fopen("passwords.csv", "r");

        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle);

        print $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1]. "<BR>";

        }
        if ($username === $line_of_text[0] && $email === $line_of_text[1] ){
            echo "yes";
        } else{
            echo "no";
        }
```

Comment: "I want to extract login details from a csv file in my php. My code only accepts the last values in the csv file" these are two statements of fact. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

May be the answer you are looking for is this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $username= $_POST['name'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $file_handle = fopen("passwords.csv", "r");
    $found = FALSE;

    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle);

        print $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1]. "<BR>";

        if ($username === $line_of_text[0] && $email === $line_of_text[1] )
        {
            $found = TRUE;
        }
    }
    if ($found){
        echo "yes";
    } else{
        echo "no";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while (! feof($file_handle)) {
    print_r(fgetcsv($file_handle));
}
```

Comment: I've tried this. Yet when I try logging in with any other username and email aside the last username and email in the csv file, it doesnt work